# stop applescript script from running on keypress ESC

Tags: applescript

I have an applescript that sends keystrokes to TextEdit. I need to be able to stop the script at any time from simply pressing the ESC key. I tried some examples online I found but none seem to be working. I have no idea what I am doing lol. Any help would be awesome on this

This is the non working example

```
activate application "TextEdit"
repeat until (keys pressed) is {"esc"}
    set keys_pressed to keys pressed
    if keys_pressed is not {} then
        tell application "System Events"
            key code 18
        end tell
        delay (random number from 0.2 to 0.3)
        tell application "System Events"
            key code 19
        end tell
        delay (random number from 0.2 to 0.3)
    end if
end repeat
```

Comment: How are you running the script? An alternative is to define a 2nd script (using whatever language) whose purpose is to kill the AppleScript, and attach a global hotkey to it (though ESC wouldn't work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im sorry but I don't think you can do this with just AppleScript, but I recommend Cocoa-AppleScript, Download Xcode and make a Cocoa AppleScript App, Cocoa AppleScript allows you to use Cocoa Windows linked to Applescript Code, you can then make a Menubar item to stop the repeating

Comment: ugh if Macs could be as simple as Autoit

Comment: Good advice; @CesarBielich: if you want to stick with a scripting language (rather than creating a Swift-based Cocoa application), consider using JXA (JavaScript for Automation), available since OS X 10.10. It is a superior alternative to AppleScript with a built-in ObjC bridge. Documentation is sparse, unfortunately, but the [JXA Cookbook](https://github.com/dtinth/JXA-Cookbook) is a good starting point.